# Why or why not a shorthand for core functions for certain data types?

Tags: javascript, ruby, function, elm

In Ruby, you can write something like `"hello".upcase`, while in many other languages such as Javascript and Elm, this requires a style like `String.upcase("hello")`. This feels redundant.

Does any language implement a shorthand for functions tied to core data types (strings, lists/arrays, etc.) when the name of the library expresses the data type of a certain argument of the function (e.g. functions like `String.upcase(string_type_argument)`), perhaps `[special character]upcase(string_type_argument)`? Are there pros or cons to this?

I realize that in Elm, one option is to import the functions (e.g. `import String exposing (..)` or `import String exposing (some, specific, functions)`), but they are confusing (importing the whole core libraries with potentially overlapping function names), or annoying with extra work (keeping the specific function imports up to date with what's being used or not used).

Comment: in JS you can totally do `'neuro'.toUpperCase()` // that works just fine

Comment: Hm. Not sure how I forgot that.

Comment: ^ a string still has the prototype methods. You use `String.someMethod()` if you require a standalone use on a non-string (or a string, but that's redundant)

Comment: I'm not really sure how you want this question to be answered. It feels very broad. Can you clarify exactly what you want to know?

Comment: It is just a matter of how object oriented the language is.

Comment: Yeah, I think what happened is I got focused on Elm and forgot that this really is a question that applies mostly to non-OO languages. With that context, I am curious if there are useful shorthands for this kind of thing in functional languages.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript works with prototypes, lets take strings for example:

The `String.prototype` is essentially a container for all the string manipulation methods.

**An example:**

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {
 // makes the string uppercase and returns it
 // this is a native method
}
```

You can simply call this function on ANY string like so:

```
'var name = 'john';

name.toUpperCase() = //JOHN;'
```

Or even:

```
'john'.toUpperCase();
```

Now, lets assume the toUpperCase function didn't exist, and we had to replicate its functionality

We could it a couple of ways:

Add it to the String.prototype:

```
String.prototype.NEWUPPERCASEFUNCTION = function() {
  // we can refer to the 'string' that is always left of the dot with 'this'   
  // which is a reserved word in JS:
  return 'this' in uppercase
}
```

This is generally **frowned** upon, and can cause issues

Another, more usual way is, to just create a function where you pass in a string and return a uppercase version of that string, or that string after 'uppercasing' it:

```
function upperCaser(string) {
 // not gonna write out the logic here, but you get it
 return updated string
}
```

Comment: This answer kind of went on a JavaScript tangent. The question isn't necessarily JS-centric.

Comment: Agreed, well sorta, but hopefully this gets the convo going. If there is one to be had..

Answer (score 1):

There is virtually no difference between a format such as `String.doThing("str")` and `"str".doThing()`. In Java, this difference is referred to as "static" vs "instance" methods.

There certainly **are** languages out there which have shorthand coding formats, but the only difference is in the brevity of *source* code. The "compiler" still generates the same "compiled" code (or very similar).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that Ruby and JavaScript are object oriented languages, while Elm is a pure functional language.

In an object oriented language, the paradigm is to define a class (like the `String` class) that packages together some local state along with some methods. The methods have access to read the local state and to modify it. `"str"` is an instance of the `String` class and so it has methods that can be called "on it" that have access to that internal state, and so can for instance return `"STR"`.

Elm is a pure functional language. It doesn't have objects, just values and functions that take those values and return other values. Functions are grouped together into "modules", but the modules don't have any local state since there is no such thing as "an instance of a module".

The possibly confusing part is that Elm has both a `String` type *and* a `String` module that packages up a bunch of functions that act on strings.

So `"str"` is a value of type `String`, and `toUpper` is a function that takes a value of type `String` and returns another value of type `String`. It is defined inside the `String` module so you call it like `String.toUpper("str")`, but `String` is the module, not the type.